# How can i place a container before a ListView Widget

Tags: flutter, listview

I'm trying to place a container before the contents of a listview but some how the container isn't rendered when i run the app.
My code

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http ;

  class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
  }

   class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
   String url="https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10";
       
  Future<List<dynamic>>  fetchPlayers() async{
    final result = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  return json.decode(result.body)['results'];

   }

 String name(dynamic player){
return player['name']['first'] + " " + player['name'] 
 ['last'];
 
 }

String position(dynamic player){
return  player['name']['last'];
  }

@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
 
  body: Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(35, 45, 30, 20),
  child:

   FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
      future: fetchPlayers(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot 
      snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                child: Text("I want a container here"),
              ),

           ListView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int 
             index){
                return
                  Card(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ListTile(
                          leading: CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 30, backgroundImage: 
                     NetworkImage(
                              snapshot.data[index] 
                             ['picture']['large'])),
                           
                         title: 
                         Text(name(snapshot.data[index])),
                          subtitle: 
                     Text(position(snapshot.data[index])),
                        
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
              })


            ]
          );
          
        }
        else{
          return Center(child: 
          CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
     
  },
 
         
      
     
   


    ),)
    


   );
   }
```

The contents of a container are not seen when i run my app.I'm not really familiar with flutter i guess i'm doing something wrong.
Could someone help please

UPDATE :
I wanted my container to be displayed after the data has been loaded.After following an approach shown below ,now the container is seen but the data of the `ListView` are not.

Target is something like this
[image]

Comment: could you please include the image of the ui you want?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not returning that container anywhere it would not get displayed  by before if you mean

1. I want to display the container before the data is loaded (so for the loading duration) try

```
   return Container(child: Text("...
```

2. I want to display the container at the top of the list there are a few options

   a. Move the container outside of the FutureBuilder if you want it to be shown in every case regardless
   b. Create a `List<Widget> widgets = []` in the builder function of FutureBuilder and add the container and any other widget that should be displayed and return the list in the end of the builder function

Comment: Adding a return keyword makes the rest of the code be dead code

Comment: yes try the creating a list approach

Answer (score 0):

Just add `return` keyword before `Container`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see Container() before loading data. You need to do

```
Column(
 children:[
    Container(...),
    FuturueBuilder<List<dynamic>>(...)
  ]
)
```

or you want it to see when data is loaded

```
return Column(
 children: [
  Container(...),
  ListView.builder(...)
 ]
)
```

or you want to show it while data loading.

```
switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none:
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return const Container(...);
          default:
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return const Text('Error');
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(...);
            }
        }
      },
```

Comment: I want the second option , but i've tried that and only the container is shown while the contents of the listView are not

Comment: Are you fetching data correctly then shows in a correct way? Because you use snapshot.data[index] for different section of your code. When your response returned, which data class you are using to map it?

Comment: Hello , I've added my full code. Could you please take a look